# Sticky Headers on a table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a jQuery script I found on github.com which [has a license](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/license.txt)

> Copyright (c) 2011 Jonas Mosbech
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> **--snip--**

So can I assume that I can use it without breaking any copyright?

If I can I want the script to work on a named table and not all tables in the project. The problem I have is it affects all the tables in the project. Is there any way the it could be adapted to only work with a named table.

The `StickyTableHeaders.js` file has the following at the start:

```
$(function () {
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});
```

I have my table constructed as follows:

```
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test one</th>
      <th>Test two</th>
      <th>Test three</th>
      <th>Test four</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data one</td>
        <td>Data two</td>
        <td>Data three</td>
        <td>Data four</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried changing the `$("table")` to `$("#table1")` and given the table an id of the same but that does not work.

```
$(function () {
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});
```

Is there any way that I can make it work on one named table only.

Comment: You have a floating `<thead>` tag.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. Resolved